# NestJS TypeScript @db module runs without being imported and points to a directory that I did not declare

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I can not find anywhere that @db is defined. It knows to point to src/db/pickbazar but I can not find it anywhere else in the code so I assume it is defined globally somewhere. When I use Visual Studio Code to look at the definiton it just points back to the json that it references.

Here is an example from author.service.ts

```
import authorsJson from '@db/authors.json';
const authors = plainToClass(Author, authorsJson);
```

Comment: Is there a folder named db in the root of the project ?

Comment: Have you checked your `tsconfig` files? That looks like a path alias, and that's where those should be defined

Comment: It was in the tsconfig.json file in root. Thanks for the help!